# как сократить время программы

Tags: python

нужно сократить время программы до 5 секунд

```
t = int(input())
n = []
for i in range(t):
    p, a = list(map(int, input().split()))
    b = str(a ** (p - 2) % p)
    n.append(b)
print('\n'.join(n))
```

Обратное число
В этой задаче нужно ответить на `1 ≤ t ≤ 10^5` запросов. Каждый запрос состоит из двух целых чисел `2 ≤ p ≤ 10^9` и `0 < a < p`, число `p` является простым. На каждый запрос нужно вывести в отдельной строке целое число `0 < b < p` такое, что `(ab − 1) ⋮ p`.

Входные данные:

```
4
5 1
5 2
5 3
5 4
```

Выходные данные:

```
1
3
2
4
```

Задачу понял отлично, но как сократить время выполнения не имею представления.

Comment: Если честно то больше интересует как вы будете вычислять скорость при наличии `input()`. Ведь это сходу уже +1секунда в лучшем случае. У вас их 2 то есть + 2 секунды минимум. + повторное получение в цикле. В итоге вопрос а возможно ли уложиться в 5 секунд даже отбросив всю остальную логику?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Судя по строчке с `b`, вы знаете, что вычисляете обратный элемент по простому модулю `р` через возведение в степень.
Однако само возведение можно ускорить, используя функцию `pow`  с тремя аргументами.
Она и все вычисления сделает по модулю, большие числа не будут участвовать, и бинарное возведение в степень за `log p` применит

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать